# Extension Resource URL being rewritten

Tags: extension, resource-urls

When I save the Extension Resource URL it is rewritten from:

```
/var/www/vhosts/examplesite/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext
```

to

```
https://www.examplesite.com//var/www/vhosts/examplesite/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext
```

It looks like it is taking the https://www.examplesite/ part from the civicrm.settings.php file:

```
define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'https://www.examplesite.com/' );
```

I'm getting a number of errors telling me that extensions are pointing to the wrong place, so I figure I've **gone astray somewhere in the settings**. I see the Extension Resource should be the same as the CiviCRM Extensions Directory, which currently is:

```
/var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext
```

Where have I gone wrong? Any pointers much appreciated!

Edit:

So I changed the Resource URL to https://www.examplesite.com/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext, but I still seem to get an error indicating that maybe the extensions are still not pointing to the right place?

`mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/Session.php' (include_path='/var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp-1.0-beta4/:/var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/packages/:/var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/:.:/var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm:/var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages:/var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/:/var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm//packages:.:') in /var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp-1.0-beta4/mailchimp.php on line 442`

Comment: Maybe the Extension Resource URL should just be an absolute URL, like: `https://www.examplesite.com/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext` ?

Comment: That's exactly the Extension Resource URL in your case. Have a look at DaveFF answer.

Comment: Maybe the URL in the CiviCRM Extensions Directory should be the full URL: `https://www.examplesite.com/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext` rather than  `/var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext`?

Comment: Have another check through of all your entries in civicrm.settings.php

Comment: Extensions Resources URL: `https://www.examplesite.com/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/custom_ext` Extensions Directory Path: `/var/www/vhosts/examplesite.com/httpdocs/wp-content/files/civicrm/custom_ext/` (don't forget the last slash "/"). CiviCRM Base URL: `https://www.examplesite.com` (note the "s" in https:// if you are using SSL) after that cleanup caches and update paths. Also after applying this changes, as @petednz suggests double check your entries in civicrm.settings.php if after that you're still facing the same issue you might need to provide more info about your server.

Comment: Added trailing slash. Paths saved and cache cleaned. civicrm.settings.php checked and rechecked. Still getting errors!  I get this warning in the admin area, could this be something to do with it?

**WARNING: The downloader may be unable to download files which require HTTP redirection. This may be a configuration issue with PHP's open_basedir or safe_mode.**

Comment: Could it be an issue with PHP? I have just noticed the server is running cersion 5.3.3 and CiviCRM recommends at least 5.3.10. Seems odd that this would just impact the extensions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Extension Resource URL' under 'Resource URLs' is the web-accessible URL that points to the extensions directory, not the path to that directory on the server's filesystem. The path on the server belongs in 'CiviCRM Extensions Directory' under 'Directories'.

Edit: for the example shown, the 'Extension Resource URL' is 'https://ffnew/sites/default/extensions' for a 'CiviCRM Extensions Directory' of '/var/www/html/prod/drupal/sites/default/extensions'. This will differ if you're not on Drupal.

[image: Extensions URL]

Comment: Thanks Dave, this all looks to be more or less what I have now, but I am still getting an error that seems to imdicating the the extensions are going to the wrong place.